# Enable log rotation in rsyslog

Tags: java, rsyslog, logrotate, log-rotation

How to enable log rotation in rsyslog configuration. The method described in the official documentation of rsyslog using output channels is not working for me.

The script given in the official documentation of rsyslog for output channel is available here: https://www.rsyslog.com/doc/master/tutorials/log_rotation_fix_size.html

```js
module(load="imudp" TimeRequery="500")

module(load="omstdout")
module(load="omelasticsearch")

module(load="mmjsonparse")
module(load="mmutf8fix")

ruleset(name="prismaudit_rs") {
      action(type="omfile" dirCreateMode="0777" fileCreateMode="0777" file="/logs/prismaudit.log")
}

$outchannel log_rotation,/logs/prismaudit.log, 3000,/etc/log_rotation_script
*.* :omfile:$log_rotation

#input(type="imptcp" port="514")
input(type="imudp" port="514" ruleset="prismaudit_rs")
```

This is the snippet of code I am using. I have also tried adding the outputchannel part of code inside the ruleset(after action statement).

My log rotation script:
mv -f /logs/prismaudit.log /logs/log_rotation.log.1

Comment: @Dan I have added it with my question.

Comment: Please add the content of `/etc/log_rotation_script` to your question.

Comment: Also the file size (3000) inside your logrotation statement is defined in **bytes**. So it would rotate the file after the file size reaches **3000 Bytes** or **3 KB**.

Comment: @eDonkey the script added above is /etc/log_rotation_script. Also, the file is not getting rotated after 3kb size and more data is getting dumped into the same file.

Comment: @KumarRounak I have the exact issue, did you fine a working solution ?

Comment: @dmx no bro, the problem still persists

Answer (score 2):

First of all, I think you misunderstood something there and should read the documentation again.

The log rotation is not working because the content you currently have in `/etc/log_rotation_script` should be in `/etc/rsyslog.conf` or `/etc/rsydlog.d/filename.conf`, as the configuration of rsyslog is handled in there.

The only purpose of the `/etc/log_rotation_script` is to move a "full" (when the limit of currently 3KB is hit) file to another file/location.

The **`/etc/rsyslog.conf`** (simplified) would then look something like the following:

```
# Load modules
module(load="imudp")

# Set the default permissions for all log files
module(load="builtin:omfile"
    fileOwner="root"
    fileGroup="adm"
    fileCreateMode="0777"
    dirCreateMode="0777")

# Receive logs over udp from somewhere
input(type="imudp" address="127.0.0.1" port="514")

# log everything to /logs/prismaudit.log by using the output channel
*.* :omfile:$log_rotation

# If max file size (50MB) is reached execute /path/to/log_rotation_script
$outchannel log_rotation,/logs/prismaudit.log, 52428800,/path/to/log_rotation_script
```

---

The script which is executed when the max file size is reached, could then just move the file:

**`/path/to/log_rotation_script`**

```
# move original log to (a kind of) backup log file
mv -f /logs/prismaudit.log /logs/prismaudit.log.1
```

Comment: Hey, I mistakenly told that thing about log rotation script. I have updated the question with the log rotation script. Also, one doubt: How does this line: *.* :omfile:$log_rotation, ensures that flogs are written to /logs/prismaudit.log location.

Answer (score 0):

currently I use *Template* feature for sort the different sources that RSyslog receives:

```
$template mylogs,"/disk2/syslog/%$YEAR%%$MONTH%%$DAY%/%FROMHOST-IP%.log"
```

with this I have my logs sorted. Like you see I use *RSyslog Propierties*.

Now, I want apply the rotation by size. Currently, I use logrotate but I don't like and I've found that RSyslog have the *Output Channels* feature.

I have read that *RSyslog Propierties* only can be used in Templates and Conditional Statements and then seem that the field filename of *Output Channels* must to be static.

Do you know if it is feasible to get the same that I have with Template with Output Channels?

thanks